# Make sure this class is defined as a service and tagged with "doctrine.fixture.orm"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, fixtures

I'm trying to debug my fixtures on Symfony and I have this error:

[The "App\Entity\Mappool" fixture class is trying to be loaded, but is not available. Make sure t

his class is defined as a service and tagged with "doctrine.fixture.orm".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Grs.png)

My entity

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MappoolRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MappoolRepository::class)
 */
class Mappool
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $follow;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MappoolMap::class, mappedBy="mappool")
     */
    private $mappoolMaps;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Step::class, mappedBy="mappool")
     */
    private $steps;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=PoolSet::class, inversedBy="mappools")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $poolSet;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MappoolFollowed::class, mappedBy="mappool", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $mappoolFolloweds;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Contributor::class, inversedBy="mappools")
     */
    private $Contributor;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mappoolMaps = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->steps = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->mappoolFolloweds = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getThumbnail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    public function setThumbnail(?string $thumbnail): self
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFollow(): ?int
    {
        return $this->follow;
    }

    public function setFollow(int $follow): self
    {
        $this->follow = $follow;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|MappoolMap[]
     */
    public function getMappoolMaps(): Collection
    {
        return $this->mappoolMap;
    }

    public function addMappoolMap(MappoolMap $mappoolMap): self
    {
        if (!$this->mappoolMaps->contains($mappoolMap)) {
            $this->mappoolMaps[] = $mappoolMap;
            $mappoolMap->setMappool($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMappoolMap(MappoolMap $mappoolMap): self
    {
        if ($this->mappoolMaps->removeElement($mappoolMap)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($mappoolMap->getMappool() === $this) {
                $mappoolMap->setMappool(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Step[]
     */
    public function getSteps(): Collection
    {
        return $this->steps;
    }

    public function addStep(Step $step): self
    {
        if (!$this->steps->contains($step)) {
            $this->steps[] = $step;
            $step->setMappool($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPoolSet(): ?PoolSet
    {
        return $this->poolSet;
    }

    public function setPoolSet(?PoolSet $poolSet): self
    {
        $this->poolSet = $poolSet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|MappoolFollowed[]
     */
    public function getMappoolFolloweds(): Collection
    {
        return $this->mappoolFolloweds;
    }

    public function addMappoolFollowed(MappoolFollowed $mappoolFollowed): self
    {
        if (!$this->mappoolFolloweds->contains($mappoolFollowed)) {
            $this->mappoolFolloweds[] = $mappoolFollowed;
            $mappoolFollowed->setMappool($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeStep(Step $step): self
    {
        if ($this->steps->removeElement($step)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($step->getMappool() === $this) {
                $step->setMappool(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMappoolFollowed(MappoolFollowed $mappoolFollowed): self
    {
        if ($this->mappoolFolloweds->removeElement($mappoolFollowed)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($mappoolFollowed->getMappool() === $this) {
                $mappoolFollowed->setMappool(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContributor(): ?Contributor
    {
        return $this->Contributor;
    }

    public function setContributor(?Contributor $Contributor): self
    {
        $this->Contributor = $Contributor;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Fixture

```
<?php


namespace App\DataFixtures;


use App\Entity\Mappool;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class MappoolFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
            $mappool = new Mappool();
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $date->setDate(2021, 12 , 1 + $i);
            $mappool->setName('name_' . $i);
            $mappool->setThumbnail('thumbnail_' . $i);
            $mappool->setFollow($i);
            $mappool->setUpdatedAt($date);
            $mappool->setCreatedAt($date);
            $mappool->setPoolSet($this->getReference('poolSet_' . $i));
            $mappool->setContributor($this->getReference('contributor_' . $i));
            $manager->persist($mappool);
            $this->addReference('mappool_' . $i, $mappool);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            ContributorFixtures::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

For dependencies, I just follow error message to generate them (I don't understand how doctrine read fixtures).

Answer (score 3):

After some research, it was my fault  :
i use
`Mappool::class` 
instead of
`MappoolFixtures::class`

on
 `getDependencies()`